# Riemann Theta function in sage/sympy/Python?

Tags: python, math, sympy, sage

Is there a library function to compute the [Riemann Theta function](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-247/S0025-5718-03-01609-0/S0025-5718-03-01609-0.pdf) (not Zeta) in sympy/sage/Python?

I have looked at the docs and can't find anything but I wonder if I have just missed it under a different name maybe.

As an example of what I would like to do, here is some Maple code.

```
> evalf(RiemannTheta([0,0],Matrix([[3*I/Pi, 0],[0,3*I/Pi]])));
                              1.2090903064 + 0. I
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking a bit, I found this function : `mpmath.zeta`

Here's the relevant doc : http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/mpmath/functions/zeta.html

---

Sorry, I mixed my Greek letters here.

Would this do the trick ? : https://github.com/abelfunctions/abelfunctions/wiki/Getting%20Started

Comment: That's out by 2 Greek letters.

Comment: Would this work ? https://github.com/abelfunctions/abelfunctions/wiki/Getting%20Started

Comment: Sadly zeta != theta.

Comment: That github link looks interesting! Thank you. I will test it out.

Comment: Do you understand how to install sage packages? I downloaded the zip and unzipped it. The changed into abelfunctions-master  and ran `tar cjf abelfunctions.spkg /home/user/Downloads/abelfunctions-master/abelfunctions/`and then ran `sudo sage -p -c abelfunctions.spkg`.

Comment: This complains that I shouldn't be using sudo and then gives me `Finished extraction
/usr/lib/sagemath/build/bin/sage-spkg: line 573: cd: abelfunctions: No such file or directory` and so fails. What are you supposed to do?

Comment: You may be in the wrong directory.  Note the "chat room" https://gitter.im/abelfunctions/abelfunctions and follow https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-support/N52kz-rHIko which may in fact be you, or maybe someone else with the same problem.

Comment: @kcrisman That answer was to rename the abelfunctions-master directory to abelfunctions it seems.

Comment: Sweet!  Hope you have fun with it.